# Ignore empty values on average math, but show it as zero on result

Tags: mysql, sql, average, aggregate-functions, sql-null

I need to calculate the `Average` value of fields, but two things needs to happen:

1- The empty values should NOT be counted for the average math.
2- If the field is empty it still must be shown in the result (with avg === 0)

Imagine that I have this dataset:

```
-----------------------
Code | valField | Date
-----------------------
  A  |          | 2020-09-08
  B  |  12      | 2020-09-09
  A  |  10      | 2020-09-08
  B  |  15      | 2020-09-09
  B  |          | 2020-09-09
  C  |          | 2020-09-09
```

So I need the average of the `day`. As you can see,  we have:
A = { empty, 10 }
B = { 12, 15, empty }
C = { empty }

I need to make the average like this:
Average of A = 10
Average of B = (12+15)/2  (because we have 2 non-empty values)
Average of C = 0  (It has not a single value, but I need it to show on result as 0)

So far I could accomplish both of the requirements, but not in the same time.

This query will show empty values BUT will also count empty fields on `average math`

```
SELECT AVG(valField) FROM myTable;
```

So Average of B would be = (12+15+0)/3 - wrong!

Now this will ignore empty values, the AVG math will be correct, but `C` would NOT be shown.

```
SELECT AVG(valFIeld) FROM myTable WHERE valField <> ''
```

How may I accomplish both requirements?

Comment: What datatype have `valField`? Please provide your table structure.

Comment: Hi! @SlavaRozhnev `valField` can be  `integer` or `empty` (not null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment I understood, you have `valField` defined as varchar, so you can use next trick:

```
select 
    Code, 
    coalesce(avg(nullif(valField, '')), 0) as avg_value
from tbl 
group by Code;
```

Test the query on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=f1bd004ae5dc82138b75a90a2451bc8d&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Here I used [NULLIF](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_nullif.asp) function for convert empty values to null before calculate the average

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your reply. It is probably right, as it's returning me the average of each code (one of each), but I need the average of each day, so I'll have all codes with it's average value for each day on the database.

Comment: So, just add `Date` into `group by` and select sections of query

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT code, COALESCE(AVG(valField), 0) FROM myTable GROUP BY code
```

This assumes `valField` is of a numeric datatype, and that by *empty* you mean `null`.

Here is what happens behind the hood:

- `avg()`, as most other aggregate functions, ignores `null` values
- if all values are `null`, then `avg()` does return `null`; you can replace that with `0` using `coalesce()`

Comment: Hello! Actually I indeed meant empty. The database is not null, but some values are just empty ` '' `. It still counting empty rows on `AVG()`. If there are 10 rows, but only 5 of them have values, the average should divide the sum only by 5 not all 10s. On the other hand, if a code has ONLY empty values, so it should return 0.  Also, forgot to mention, I'm grouping by `date` in format of `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy just create two queries one that calculates the average using non null values and the other one calculating the codes having no value in the data.

```
select round(avg(valField)) as avg, code from new where valField is not null group by Code
union all
select 0 as avg, code from new  group by Code having avg(valField) is null;
```